# Spring Kafka SeekToCurrentErrorHandler maxFailures doesn't work when concurrency level is less than partition number

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using spring kafka 2.2.7 and my consumer configuration code is following:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfiguration {

  @Bean
  ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Customer> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Customer> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    // less than number of partition, will do infinite retry
    factory.setConcurrency(1);
    SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler =
        new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((record, exception) -> {
          LOGGER.info("***in error handler data, {}", record);
        }, 1);
    factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, Customer> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
  }

  @Bean
  public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.class);
    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);

    props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://127.0.0.1:8081");
    props.put("specific.avro.reader", "true");

    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    return props;
  }
}


@Component
@Slf4j
public class KafkaConsumerService {

  @KafkaListener(id = "demo-consumer-stream-group", topics = "kafka-demo-avro")
  public void process(ConsumerRecord<String, Customer> record) {
    LOGGER.info("Customer key: {} and value: {}", record.key(), record.value());
    LOGGER.info("topic: {}, partition: {}, offset: {}", record.topic(), record.partition(), record.offset());
    throw new RuntimeException("force to retry");
  }
}
```

So, if I have an exception happening in my listener, the consumer will retry the failed message forever even I config the maxFailures in the configuration if the concurrency level I specified is less than the partition counts for my topic.

It will only work if i send the message one by one at least a second interval. If I send the message as a batch, the behaviour wouldn't work. Unless I restart the consumer and it will work properly.

Step to reproduce:
1. create a topic with more than 1 partition, for example 3 or 6
2. In Spring kafka config, specify concurrency level to 1
3. For `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`, specify `maxFailure` to a positive value for example 3
4. Send dozen of messages to the topic

You will see each failed message will do infinite retry instead of the `maxFailure` I specified. Also, I can see a lot of messages fall behind of the consumer lag.

However, if you stop the listener and start the listener again, it will skip the failed messages properly.

Comment: There is nothing like send "messages in batch" in Spring Kafka, neither in plain Kafka. The producer is fully not related to consumer. And this is the main point of messaging. I don't say anything about your original problem: just want to be sure that we are on the same page and speak the same language. Any chances to have a simple project from you to play with? It is going to be much easier for us to investigate and determine an issue if that

Comment: Yeah, I should say in batch should say stream of messages. We are on the same page with this. Back to the original problem, it's very simple spring kafka consumer setup with the code i put here. If I put concurrency to 1 and the partition is bigger than 1 will have this issue. Only the concurrency is same as partition the issue will gone.

Comment: I still want to have some project to play with and some description what to expect. Well, simple test-case would be great, too. This way we would understand what is expected. I just don't see the way how can I determine that retry doesn't work properly... Thanks for understanding. My knowledge in this topic is limited, but looks like no one can help you at the moment. So, please bear with me

Comment: Please look at this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57859158/infinite-retries-with-seektocurrenterrorhandler-in-kafka-consumer sounds like the same problem as mine one.

Comment: BTW, is @Gary Russell still around the community and whether he can explain this?

Comment: No, he's not until the next week.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I mean it will do infinitely retry not the behaviour we set in the SeekToErrorHandler

Comment: OK. So, any project from you, please? I'm not sure that my one is going to do the same as yours.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I updated the code above and use this code you can reproduce the issue. Just create a topic with more than 1 partition. Try to send more messages for example 30, to the topic. NB: you may not reproduce this issue if you just send one or two messages. It wouldn't skip the current failed message even the maxFailure I specified is 1, instead it will do infinite retry.

Comment: I don't have Avro Schema Registry. Can I reproduce it without that one? What should I do to let it to fail? That's one I'm asking about simple Spring Boot project, so we will play in exactly the same environment without any side stories.

Comment: Ah! OK. I see: `throw new RuntimeException("force to retry");`. So, Avro is just redundant in this case...

Comment: It would have same issue even without Kafka avro. Just see the listener i have in the code, I specifically throw exception there in order to make it fail.

Comment: Yes, forget about avro, just use json or the string for message. It will all behaviour the same. Also, see the other SO talking about the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57859158/infinite-retries-with-seektocurrenterrorhandler-in-kafka-consumer

Comment: OK. Thanks making Spring Boot project to play with...

Comment: I also updated the post with steps how you can reproduce this issue easily. I still think it's a bug of spring kafka instead of a config issue. Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue: https://github.com/artembilan/sandbox/tree/master/so57889424

Comment: So, I have a `@KafkaListener` with an explicit exception, a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` with `3` retries, topic with `6` partition. I send `20` records at once. I see in logs retries for each record consumed, bot no one goes beyond `maxFailures`. So, what is wrong with my config that I don't see such a problem? And pay attention how test case confirms that everything as expected. I

Comment: I don't mind that there might be some bug in the project, but we need something to reproduce it, so we would know what and how to fix. Thanks for understanding

Comment: What is the concurrency number you specify for the factory? Try set it with `1`

Comment: I did, see `application.properties`: https://github.com/artembilan/sandbox/blob/master/so57889424/src/main/resources/application.properties#L1. Well, for more efficiency it would be better when you provide a reproducible project

Comment: I saw your code and you are using Spring embedded Kafka but we are using Confluent Kafka I am guessing this could be the issue. But i can give a try using embedded.

Comment: Well, there is no a thing like Confluent Kafka, but Apache Kafka. Also, an Embedded one is just syntax sugar: the same Apache Kafka Broker distributive is used to start a process in the JVM. I will try tomorrow against standalone Kafka Broker...

Comment: Also another configuration difference is `ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG` you set it to be true.

Comment: Ok. I’ll try that tomorrow as well. Thanks for heads up!

Comment: It still passes for me even with `spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false`

Comment: BTW I'm using latest Spring Boot `2.1.8.RELEASE`, which brings for me Spring Kafka `2.2.8.RELEASE`. Maybe something has been fixed since there... Would you mind to try it?

Comment: It even works against an external Kafka Broker... So, something is definitely missing in my configuration to make it fail as your solution.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I just upgraded to Spring Kafka `2.2.8.RELEASE` and it works. Looks like it's a bug for `2.2.7` and been fixed with latest release. Thanks for your great help.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug for Spring Kafka `2.2.7.RELEASE` but fixed in `2.2.8.RELEASE`.

Comment: That's great! Only the problem I can't determine which commit made the fix: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/releases/tag/v2.2.8.RELEASE

Comment: Yes, exactly. I also tried to find out what's the fix but I can't find any commits related to this.

Comment: See also this one: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1234. It turns out with multi-partition we may have a disorder for records after seeking

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 2.2.8 and I can still reproduce the bug, but with a bit more intricate configuration. I need to have both `SeekToCurrentEH` and `retryTemplate` with `ExponentialRandomBackOffPolicy`. So there's still a risk of running into it.
Reported [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1234).